# MS .Net chart control: displaying pie data labels outside the pie

Tags: .net-4.0, pie-chart, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to display pie chart data labels outside the pie in the Microsoft .Net chart control, just like SSRS pie chart's series `CustomAttributes.PieLabelStyle=Outside` does?

I tried to use the below properties to no avail:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is in .NET you need to set

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "outside"
```

Hope this answer your question.

Regards,
Ramzy!

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you! How did you find that out?